# Getting elements in an Json array

Tags: arrays, json

I am having trouble getting values out of an json array using c#.

This is the json code:

```
{"page":0,"maxElementsPerPage":"2","maxElements":"2","elements":[{"timestamp":"2018-06-20 19:59:30","content":"abc","lat":"...","lng":"..."},...
```

The code I have been using to get e.g. the value of content in the first array is:

```
elements[0].content
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the content properties:

```
content = elements.Select(x => x.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: this should explain it. what has to be changed then?

Comment: {"page":0,"maxElementsPerPage":"2","maxElements":"2","elements":[{"timestamp":"2018-06-20 19:59:30","content":"abc","lat":"...","lng":"..."}]}